# MVC3 - how to close jquery dialog from controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

does anyone know how to close jquery dialog and refresh the grid (using telerik grid) from controller after inserting/updating records in db?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The controller runs on the server, jquery on the client. So executing javascript from the controller is out of the question. On the other hand you could use the `success` callback of your AJAX call to close the dialog:

```
$('#dialog').dialog('close');
```